# Bigquery - Select all table and partition in dataset

Tags: google-bigquery, wildcard

I want to select all data in the datasets. I know I can use wildcard. but the problem is there's a partition table within the dataset

example data:

```
data_2021_05_04 <- partition table
data_2021_05_05 <- partition table
data_2021_05_06 <- normal table
data_2021_05_07 <- normal table
```

if I use
`select * from dataset.data_*`
it will return

> Wildcard table over non partitioning tables and field based partitioning tables is not yet supported

or

> Wildcard matched incompatible partitioning tables, first table1, first incompatible table table2

Is there's anyway to solve this?

thank you

Comment: bigquery now supports ALTER TABLE Rename, you could consider renaming the conflicting tables, or merge them under the partition structure? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_table_rename_to_statement

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me :

SELECT * FROM `ProjectID.DatasetID.TableID_*` LIMIT 1000